# How to add Topics names containing spaces to FeedItem using hashtag via apex

Tags: apex, chatter, feeditem, topics

I have written some apex to 'auto-tag' a record to a Topic if that topic keyword is mentioned in one of the description fields for said record.  This will ensure that anyone who follows that topic will see the record in their feed - without the record creator adding the topic manually.

By adding a record to the `FeedItem` 'table' and simply adding the #topic to the body text - it automatically creates the topic assignment.  This works very well for single word topics.

The issue is with topic names that have a space in them - when I add the `#Topic Name` hash tag, it creates a new topic for the `#Topic` part but the 'Name' part is treated as normal text.  It subsequently creates a new Topic and assigns this to the `FeedItem` in the `TopicAssignment` object.

Is there some sort of delimiter that I can use so when I insert a record into `FeedItem` that contains hashtags (topics) it will pick up the whole hash tag with spaces? - I tried double quotes but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, here's the syntax:

```
#[multi-word topic]
```

Comment: How can i add topics to ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(communityId, feedType, subjectId, input,filebody);  method without adding #tags

Comment: See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92541/adding-topics-to-a-feeditem/92591