# Adding topics to a feeditem

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed

I am using the following method to share a file to a group.

```
ConnectApi.FeedItem feadItem = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(communityId, feedType, subjectId, input,filebody);
```

I want to add topic to the feed item.

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at :   
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_feed-items_FeedItemTopics.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_Feed_item_topic_page.htm

Comment: Yes but I want to add to feed item , that the road block I am facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add a topic to a feed item, you need to post the feed item first, and then call either ConnectApi.Topics.assignTopic() or ConnectApi.Topics.assignTopicByName(). It's not possible currently to assign the topic and post the feed item in a single call. See the documentation for the [ConnectApi.Topics](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_Topics_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_Topics_assignTopic) class for more info.

Comment: assignTopicByName(communityId, recordId, topicName) this method asks for recordId. How can i get the record id from the feedItem Variable ?

Comment: Use the feedItem's ID as the recordId.